# Is it possible to add a second row to the address bar area in Chrome for extension icons?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

I got very accustomed to the way Firefox and Google Toolbar worked, and now I'd liked to do something similar with Chrome.

Every extension I add that I want to see the icon for, makes my address bar shorter and shorter.

**Is there a way to put these all onto a second row, allowing the address bar to stretch across as normal.**

The end result would look something like the Google Toolbar and Firefox address bar look together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome 5 has a grab-handle on the address bar, so you can adjust the width allocated to the extension icons and force them into a drop-down menu (indicated by a <kbd>>></kbd> symbol).

But no such thing exists on Chrome 4 as far as I know, but you could try the [Chromy](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mfhnlgcnlpbbjecojebcfdleiapicaio?hl=en) extension

Ironically, I cannot see a Chrome extension which helps you tidy up the address bar and remove the clutter from all those other extensions.

Comment: Thanks, Chromy will work for now as far as hiding the "button" extension icons! Leaves more room for address bar and status/notification icons.

Comment: Chromy extension does not work anymore, but there still is grab-handle on the address bar. Since I myself had a problem finding out how to use that grab handle, here is [link](https://youtu.be/Xpx7m8_3MOo) to the video that explains how it is done.